# deleting from mongo in spring java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, exception

I am trying to delete a document from mongoDB by using spring data in java

here is my maven dependecies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.SR1</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am using MongoRepository to define my repositries in java:

```
public interface FilesInfoRepository extends MongoRepository<MyCollectionClass, String> { ... }
```

here is the brief exception:

```
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/RemoveRequest**
```

and here is the full exception:

```
 ERROR [[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/RemoveRequest] with root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/RemoveRequest
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.remove(DBCollectionImpl.java:223) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.remove(DBCollectionImpl.java:203) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.remove(DBCollection.java:300) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.remove(DBCollection.java:327) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$13.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1295) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$13.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1279) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:462) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doRemove(MongoTemplate.java:1279) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.remove(MongoTemplate.java:1265) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.delete(SimpleMongoRepository.java:155) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.delete(SimpleMongoRepository.java:164) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.delete(SimpleMongoRepository.java:176) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

my mongo is a replicaSet and is another datacenter, but I am sure that the connection is working well and other actions on mongo works well, just delete doesnot work.

update:
here is my full pom.xml:

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>Brixton.SR1</version>
<relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you may be post rest of the pom ? You may have more than one version of mongo java driver.

Comment: @Veeram I updated the question.

Comment: I don't see why this is not working. `mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar` does have `com/mongodb/RemoveRequest` class. I tired something similar with the spring boot version 1.3.5 and it works fine for me.  Just check to make sure the `mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar` is available in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Include this dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

It will work